# Problemas con PHPMailer y su configuración

Tags: php, email

Intento hacer un envío de correo a través de `PHPMailer`. Se reciben bien los datos desde el formulario pero no llega el mensaje a ningún lado.

¿Puede ser la configuración del `PHPMailer`?

```
<?php
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
if ($_POST['action'] == "send") {
//$varname = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
//$vartemp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "secure.misitio.com";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['correo'], $_POST['nombre']);
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->AddAddress("info@misitio.mx","Prueba");
//$mail->AddAddress("correo","Copia de Funcionamiento");

$body = "<strong>Formulario de Contacto</strong><br /><br /><br />";
$body.= "Nombre: ". $_POST['nombre']."<br /><br />";
$body.= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telefono'].  "<br /><br />";
$body.= "Correo: ". $_POST['correo'] . "<br /><br />";
$body.= "Cel: ". $_POST['cel'] . "<br /><br />";
$body.= "Modelo: ". $_POST['modelo'] . "<br /><br />";
$body.= "mensaje: ". $_POST ['mensaje'] . "<br /><br />";

$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Send();
} 

header("Location: gracias.php");
?>
```

Comment: Yo también estoy haciendo un evío de correo con PHPMailer y me pasa lo mismo que a ti. Si ya diste con la solución porfa ponla como respuesta. Saludos. @AlexRodríguezP

Answer (score 1):

Para usar $mail->Host debes tener un servidor smtp configurado y funcional, si quieres hacer una prueba puedes usar el servicio smtp que ofrece google, es gratis.

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Crea una nueva instancia PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Usar SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Habilita el SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//hostname del servidor de correo
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Setea numero del puerto - 587 TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Encryptacion a usar ssl o tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Autenticacion SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username para la autenticación - direccion correo gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password gmail
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//quien envia
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//direccion alternativa
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//quien recibe
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Asunto
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Cuerpo del mensaje
$mail->Body = "Gmail mail test";
//Envia el mensaje, y revisa si existen errores
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mail Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```